# run php from command line with short tags

Tags: php, linux, shell

I have a framework with a lot of file using

when I include a file from the framework the include doesn't know it's a php file and refer it as a simple text file.

now my php definition in the php.ini is use_short_tags enable, i also see it when I browse the site, it's working.

my question is how to use the framework files and let the php know to use short tags when i run my script from the command line

thanks

Comment: often php at the cli has a different config file.  You might want to play around with something like `php -r "phpinfo();" | grep \.ini` to see where yours is.

Comment: On many distros there are distinct `php.ini` files for different environments–one for commandline and another for apache/mod_php, for example. If that's not the issue, try `php -d short_open_tag=On yourscript.php` to modify the ini value during invocation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In ubuntu/debian you have to change

```
short_open_tag Off
```

to

```
short_open_tag On
```

in

```
/etc/php5/cli/php.ini
```

And you no need to restart any service after this, just use your console php.

Answer (score 12):

The INI tag can be set directly from the CLI:

```
php -d short_open_tag=On <scriptname>
```