# wp-cli commands display content of plugin files in terminal

Tags: wordpress, wp-cli

No matter what wp cli command I run. I always see the content of two plugin.php files in the terminal before the actual command results

Comment: Just a guess: maybe php-cli is set up to not allow short open tag but the apache/fcgi-version is, so it doesn't see those files as containing PHP code and prints their content?

Comment: Solved the problem. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> php-cli was set up to not allow short open tag

See this question [run php from command line with short tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22513116/run-php-from-command-line-with-short-tags) to learn how to allow short open tags